# Error de redireccionamiento Web

Tags: servidor, url, redirección, reescritura-url

Muy buenas tardes con todos, espero se encuentren bien, no se si en esta web me puedan ayudar un poco con esto, les explico:

Estoy experimentado un error al entrar a la siguiente web https://plataforma.knowmadcity.com y me redirecciona a una web distinta que es esta https://dagdesign.co.uk/, cabe destacar que la página que presenta el error está en un subdominio y el dominio principal carga con normalidad.

He revisado todo el servidor y eliminado todo lo sospechoso incluso webs viejas que tenía allí, las DNS del dominio, y lo único raro y que **No puedo borrar (porque intento hacerlo pero no se borra)** es este redireccionamiento que dejo en la captura si a alguien le ha aparecido algún error parecido o sabe como podría eliminar definitivamente este redireccionamiento por favor me orientan y gracias de antemano.

[image: Redirección no realizada]

---

Gracias a @masterguru por las recomendaciones las seguí y haciendo unos ajustes en este caso revisando la redirección dentro del servidor y en mi caso eliminando un trabajo cron que estaba también haciendo un mal apunte logré resolver, espero a alguien más le sirva esta respuesta.

Comment: Eso te ocurre porque tu dominio no tiene un certificado https válido en ese servidor cpanel, y al aceptar el aviso te redirecciona al primero que encuentra válido en ese servidor, que seguramente no es ni tuyo.  De todos modos, algo raro le ocurre porque si se intenta acceder al `http://plataforma.knowmadcity.com` (sin la S) da un error de cpanel conforme el dominio no esta bien instalado.  La IP donde tus DNS apuntan actualmente es la 149.255.60.173.  Si no es esa deberas cambiarla en tus servidores de nombres por la correcta.

Comment: Aparte de eso, revisa tus nameservers, pues estas usando 4 de los cuales dos no responden bien la IP, que son: NS32.DOMAINCONTROL.COM y NS31.DOMAINCONTROL.COM, y que debes eliminar de tu dominio seguramente

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tus recomendaciones, ya estoy probando y confirmando lo que me dices para tratar de evitar la redirección. El servidor es mío, lo compre, pero obviamente pertenece a una empresa de gestión de dominio.
Estaré avisando muchas gracias nuevamente.

Comment: Si el servidor es tuyo, entonces quiere decir que esa otra web tambien es tuya (o le vendes el espacio en tu servidor a ellos).  Y si no es así entonces es que aun no has cambiado la IP correctamente en tus servidores de nombres y aun apuntan a un servidor compartido antiguo donde esta esa otra web. Piensa que cuando hagas el cambio de IP tardará entre unos minutos y 48 horas en propagarse mundialmente, por lo tanto no esperes que el cambio sea immediato, pero puedes comprobar su propagacion en esta web: https://www.whatsmydns.net/

Comment: Nuevamente gracias por el comentario esto también lo guardaré como todos los que me dan en esta web jajaja. Logré Resolver como me dijiste,  haciendo unos ajustes en redireccionamiento y en los trabajos cron que es donde estaba un mal apunte también. Muchas gracias nuevamente.